# Why doesn't my consumer consume Integer values? (Producer-Consumer with wait and notify)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads. One is a producer (`class Deliver`), second is consumer (`class Produce`). I want to simulate door producer. So producer deliver wood that consumer can produce a door. But i do not real get how to communicate between those two threads. Now when i run my program only wood is delivered but doors are not produced. I do not get why.

```
public class Deliver implements Runnable {

    private static int MAX_STOCKPILE = 15;

    private Integer wood;

    public Deliver(Integer wood) {
        this.wood = wood;
        new Thread(this, "Deliver").start();
    }

    public synchronized void deliver() throws InterruptedException{

        Thread.sleep(500);

        if (wood < MAX_STOCKPILE) {
            wood++;
            System.out.println("Wood delivered" + " | Wood stockpile: " + wood);
            notify();
        }
        else {
            wait();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                deliver();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Produce implements Runnable{

    private Integer wood;

    public Produce(Integer wood) {
        this.wood = wood;
        new Thread(this, "Produce").start();
    }

    public synchronized void produce() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if (wood == 10) {
            wood -= 10; //produce
            System.out.println("Doors produced");
            notify();
        }
        else {
            wait();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                produce();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer wood = 0;
        new Deliver(wood);
        new Produce(wood);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it by stepping through it?

Comment: Why is your consumer called `Produce`?

Comment: I would use a third class, called it maybe `CircularBuffer` and put the wood in that.  Use the buffer instead of `Integer`.  Right now it looks as though a counter works, but what if each item the Producer makes is different?  For example characters in a stream that form a sentence.  Store each one individually so you can have a different value for each.

Comment: use a ready-made class, some implementing BlockingQueue. Let producer call put() method, and consumer call take(). In case you want to implement similar class, first learn the source code of various classes in the java.util concurrent package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now when i run my program only wood is delivered but doors are not produced. I do not get why

There are multiple issues with your code :

1. When you mark an instance method as `synchronized`, any thread entering that method will obtain a lock on `this` (i.e the instance on which the method was called). Since `this` in `Deliver` refers to a `Deliver` instance and `this` in `Produce` refers to a `Produce` instance, the `wait` and `notify` calls are practically useless in this case as they are not interested in the same objects.
2. The golden rule to remember in *Java* is that it uses *pass-by-value* semantics. Primitives and references are therefore always passed by value. While you may assume that both `Deliver` and `Produce` will be modifying the same `Integer` passed to them from `main`, that is not the case.

That said, I would highly recommend that you consider using something like an `ArrayBlockingQueue` for solving this instead of reinventing the wheel with `wait` and `notify`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (wood == 10) {
```

to

```
if (wood >= 10) {
```

in case the thread doesn't catch it when it == 10

Comment: I hurried up and do not notice that i changed wrong class. Because i have created new class that have both methods `produce()` and `deliver()` and there your answer works fine, but when methods are in separate (like in first post) class it still do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Something to note is that Integer is immutable.

When you change the reference to the Integer you are creating a new object which has no relationship to the previous object.

What you want this an object which is shared between the two threads so when you change the value (but not the reference) they are looking at the same value.

e.g.

```
wood -= 10;
```

is the same as

```
wood = Integer.valueOf(wood.intValue() - 10);
```

I suggest using `AtomicInteger` and making the reference to it `final` to ensure you don't accidentally try to change the reference.

As Andrew Jenkins suggests; if you lock, notify/wait on unrelated objects, you don't have any thread safety. Once you have a shared object, you have to lock, notify/wait on that shared object.

Comment: I'm very confused as to how the author's code could be working. Along with the reference problem, `notify()` and `wait()` do not work across objects unless explicitly referenced.

Comment: I have added comment bellow that i was hurried up and code still don't work. But still i don't get it why my object is not shared?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Since Java is always pass by value, this code wouldn't behave any differently if the OP used an int instead of Integer. I believe immutability is a side effect but the root cause is pass-by-value semantics. (Keeping aside the wait and notify argument and assuming it is implemented correctly). Also, the `Integer` class caches values so will immutability have an impact in this case?

Comment: @CKing due to pass by value, ypu have to pass a reference to a value you can mutate. The cache won't make a difference in this case but you are right that you can have this issue.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Assume that `Integer` were mutable. Would it make a difference in this particular scenario? Due to *pass by value* semantics, `wood=wood+1` would not change the value of the original `Integer` that was passed to `Deliver`and this change would not be reflected in the `Producer`s wood. The root cause of the issue here is *pass by value* IMO. Also, is caching a non issue? I thought it would cause issues once `wood` goes beyond a certain range.

Comment: @CKing references are passed by value but you can alter the shared object referenced. Say you pass an int [] you can do `num [0]++`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Agreed. But we are not talking about arrays here but scalar references passed into methods/constructors. Even if we talk about arrays, you are modifying the value pointed by the reference held in the array but not the value pointed by the original reference that was inserted in the array. Say `method1() { Integer[]arr = new Integer[1];  ref = 1; arr[0] = ref; }` and you have `method2(Integer []arr) { arr[0]++ }`. Here, `method2` wouldn't be modifying what was pointed to by `ref` in `method1`. Pass by value is a bigger culprit than immutability IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my solution into the mix, taking into account [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41963485/743868)'s advice about using AtomicInteger.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger wood = new AtomicInteger(0);
        new Deliver(wood);
        new Produce(wood);
    }
}

public class Deliver implements Runnable {

    private static int MAX_STOCKPILE = 15;

    private final AtomicInteger wood;

    public Deliver(AtomicInteger wood) {
        this.wood = wood;
        new Thread(this, "Deliver").start();
    }

    public void deliver() throws InterruptedException{

        Thread.sleep(500);
        synchronized(wood) {
            if (wood.intValue() < MAX_STOCKPILE) {
                wood.addAndGet(1);
                System.out.println("Wood delivered" + " | Wood stockpile: " + wood);
                wood.notify();
            } else {
                wood.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                deliver();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Produce implements Runnable{

    private final AtomicInteger wood;

    public Produce(AtomicInteger wood) {
        this.wood = wood;
        new Thread(this, "Produce").start();
    }

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(wood) {
            if (wood.intValue() >= 10) {
                wood.addAndGet(-10); //produce
                System.out.println("Doors produced");
                wood.notify();
            }
            else {
                wood.wait();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                produce();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Key changes:

- We use a mutable object to communicate between threads ([AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)).
- We synchronize on the mutable object, not the thread being run.

Comment: The wait-calls have to happen inside a loop that checks the condition on which the wood has to be produced/consumed, because of the spurious wakeup issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate? `run()` is creating a loop. As far as I can tell it works as expected.